# show loader after every category on home page in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, home-page, category-listing, autoloader

> On my home page I am showing all products with its categories once on
>   page load.

**But i wanted to do like for  after scrolling down ,after each category product list before next category I wanted to show loader. I don`t wanted to lazy loading plugin. My code is like this.Only once the loader comes.**

```
require(['jquery', 'ajaxscroll'], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ias = $.ias({
                container: '#homepage_category_banner',
                item: '.category_container',
                pagination: '#ajax-pagination',
                next: '.next a.category_link'
            });
            ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
                src: '<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Pragmatic_Homepage::images/loader-ihouzit.gif') ?>'
            }));
            ias.on('load', function (event) {
                event.ajaxOptions.success = function (response) {
                    $('#homepage_category_banner').append(response);
                    $('#ajax-pagination').find('.next').removeClass('next').next().addClass('next');
                }
            })
        });
    });
```